# Regarding training a model

Tags: python-3.x, database

while training I am getting this error:-

MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), (3), '2017-11-16 08:10:38.328037', '2017-11-16 08:10:20.444393', NULL, '2020-' at line 1")

can anyone help...??

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2017-11-16 08:10:38.328037', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') FROM DUAL;
```

> You need to remove 6 digit milliseconds